# Type Error Exception in Autoform (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am getting a client side exception (below) while using an update autoform. I have absolutely no idea how to debug this issue. Please note, the file in the collection gets created just fine. Its just that this exception in thrown in client side console. Apologies if this is a noob-question.

Client form:

```
{{#autoForm class="editf" id="editf" collection="ServiceProviders" type="update" doc=selectedProvider}} 
{{> afQuickField name="businessname"}} 
{{> afQuickField name="businessdesc"}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update your profile</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Helper:

```
 Template.createprovider.events = {
'submit .editf' : function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Router.go('/createdprovider');
    AutoForm.resetForm('editf');
}
```

};

collection hooks:

```
ServiceProviders.after.update(function (userId, doc) {
  Meteor.call('UpdateAddressAndLocation', userId, doc);
});
```

exception:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking '/serviceproviders/update': TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
at Object.autoFormResetForm [as resetForm] (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?b2b90d28d5cc29be68358bb3c8bb8a337992a7dd:2127:26)
at autoFormActionCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?b2b90d28d5cc29be68358bb3c8bb8a337992a7dd:6494:22)
at CollectionHooks.defineAdvice.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/packages/matb33_collection-hooks.js?6be355737d1b00b2f05a3c833db2d77cd78d8d47:419:23)
at wrappedCallbackForParsingServerErrors (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?fdc7f0975dd1b3446ea4afd5f820cb1242a521af:455:15)
at _.each.Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function).wrappedCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo.js?3cfe0c5981c197df33036a37574850f057e934a6:621:9)
at Meteor.bindEnvironment [as _callback] (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:983:22)
```

**EDIT: Working Code:**
This needs to be placed along with the submit hook. `this.done()` calls onSuccess.

```
onSuccess: function(doc, result) {
        Router.go('/createdprovider');
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try interverting `AutoForm.resetForm('editf');` with `Router.go('/createdprovider');` ?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding, but what does "interverting" mean? FYI, I get same error even when I do not reset the form ie. if I delete the this line `AutoForm.resetForm('editf');` , I get same error.....

Answer (score 0):

Autofrom has its own properties .... You cannot use autoform id to get values on submission.

Example:

```js
AutoForm.hooks({
  YourFormid: {
    onSubmit: function (doc) {
      PeopleSchema.clean(doc);
      console.log("People doc with auto values", doc);
      this.done();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

This is the correct way to use hooks and use "doc=this"

Comment: Thanks for the correct way to do this. This approach get rids of the error, though I still dont understand the cause of the exception. Also, When I do the same as you suggested above, `Router.go('/createdprovider');` does not seem to work. My code looks like `AutoForm.hooks({
  YourFormid: {
    onSubmit: function (doc) {
      PeopleSchema.clean(doc);
      console.log("People doc with auto values", doc);
      Router.go('/createdprovider'); this.done(); 
      return false;  } }});`